# Verb for making someone an enemy

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I have seen this question answered before with the word "antagonize", but that is not what I want as I feel like that is provoking someone in an attempt to get them to lash back out at you. The word I am looking for would be like the opposite of "victimize", such as a government might want to portray certain countries as enemies so they might spread propaganda to "enemize" individuals. Not necessarily interacting with the enemy, but merely spreading information making them appear as an enemy.

Answer (score 2):

To '**alienate**' is to unfriend a former associate.

> to cause to be estranged : to make unfriendly, hostile, or indifferent especially where attachment formerly existed

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alienate)

> Trump certainly doesn't want to alienate alt-right.

[Yellow Hammer News - April 2019](https://yellowhammernews.com/doug-jones-trump-certainly-doesnt-want-to-alienate-alt-right/)

Answer (score 0):

From the text of your question, I believe you want a word for a powerful organization making a broad population consider someone to be their enemy? (As opposed to making that particular person angry). For that purpose I suggest any of these:

### demonize

To portray as evil.
This is a common approach of states in wartime, and might be the best suited to your question of a government wanting to make some people or some countries be considered the enemy by the general population.

> It is a banal fact that political leaders of nations fighting wars habitually demonize the enemy.

Jules Boykoff (2007). Beyond bullets: the suppression of dissent in the United States. ISBN 978-1-904859-59-8.

### vilify

Derives from the Latin word "vilificare", which was the verb for making something "vilis" (vulgar or vile).

> Meghan Markle is being ‘vilified and chased’ by the tabloid press in the same way the late princess Diana was, Hollywood superstar George Clooney has told an Australian magazine.

https://www.nst.com.my/lifestyle/groove/2019/02/459890/meghan-vilified-press-diana-clooney

### denigrate

To make someone, or someone's achievements, seem worthless.

> When "denigrate" was first used in English in the 16th century, it meant to cast aspersions on someone's character or reputation. Eventually, it developed a second sense of "to make black" ("factory smoke denigrated the sky"), but this sense is somewhat rare in modern usage. Nowadays, of course, "denigrate" can also refer to belittling the worth or importance of someone or something.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denigrate)

### impugn

To indicate that someone is dishonourable or unworthy

Answer (score 0):

[Foment](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/foment) : to instigate or foster (discord, rebellion, etc.); promote the growth or development of

[Inflame](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inflame) : to kindle or excite (passions, desires, etc.).

[Provoke](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/provoke) : to stir up, arouse, or call forth (feelings, desires, or activity)

[Kindle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kindle) : to excite; stir up or set going; animate; rouse; inflame